# why does python takes longer time to sort a copy of list?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, timeit

Why is there so much difference when sorting x and y and y is just a copy of x? Does python not copy the list right away?

```
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'y=list(x); x.sort()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 19.5 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'y=list(x); y.sort()'
1000 loops, best of 3: 211 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'x.sort()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 usec per loop
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters He made a copy on the first one.

Comment: @njzk2: no, to the contrary. It should be part of the test, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first and last examples have to sort the list **just once**. After that, the sorting algorithm Python uses has an easy time of it as it is optimised to take advantage of *already sorted sequences*.

From the [Wikipedia article on TimSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) (the Python sorting algorithm):

> The algorithm finds subsequences of the data that are already ordered, and uses that knowledge to sort the remainder more efficiently.

In other words, the `list(y); y.sort()` case is *disadvantaged* because it is given a clean, unsorted list each time. The `x.sort()` case is  given a fully sorted list (after the first iteration). After all, `list.sort()` sorts *in place*, altering the list. The `timeit` test does not create a copy for each test, so subsequent tests re-use the same list.

If you switch to using the `sorted()` function, you'll see no time advantage anymore, as `sorted()` returns a *new, copied and sorted list* instead of sorting in-place:

```
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'y=list(x); sorted(x)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 151 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'y=list(x); sorted(y)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 usec per loop
python -mtimeit -s'import random; x=range(1000); random.shuffle(x)' 'sorted(x)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 152 usec per loop
```

Comment: One addition for the interested reader: One should use `sorted` (which doesn't sort in-place) for timing comparisons or put the creation of the random list inside the test (but that somewhat spoils the timings).